# Is there a way to have a div overlap any website (sticky notes application)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to do something similar to sticky notes except now I'm not sure if this can actually be done with web development. I have this div that I want to overlap on  a website like a sticky note. Just have it be stationary on a website even when your start interacting with another website. Do you know if this is possible to do with any web development languages?

So far I have this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#mydivheader {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
</style>
<body>

<div id="mydiv">
  <div id="mydivheader">Click here to move</div>
  <p>1st Block</p>
</div>


<script>
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));


function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are trying to do. You wrote that you want a 'way to have a div overlap any website', but haven't you already achieved this (see below)? You already set the z index to 1 in css, and you haven't given any problem with your code. Are you trying to write this for a specific website or as a browser extension? If the latter, you should first try this out as a simple user-script, in an application such as greasemonkey. please let me know if I got anything wrong, and maybe edit and clarify your question and your intended application.

```js
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));


function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1 !important; 
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#mydivheader {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
  <div id="mydivheader">Click here to move</div>
  <p>1st Block</p>
</div>
<div>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut et magna eget libero imperdiet accumsan nec vel nisl. Aliquam erat volutpat. Integer tortor lorem, feugiat eget erat eget, aliquet suscipit sapien. Phasellus ultrices leo id scelerisque imperdiet. Suspendisse volutpat pulvinar erat, eget vehicula tellus ultrices a. Aenean tristique efficitur volutpat. Cras eleifend varius mi, a hendrerit magna elementum sit amet. Donec diam tellus, dictum vel vestibulum quis, fermentum eu tellus. Fusce vulputate justo a mauris ultricies pretium. Sed venenatis ipsum consectetur lacus imperdiet, in commodo nisl lacinia. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam pellentesque quam lacus. Suspendisse facilisis vel arcu sit amet sodales.
</p>
</div>
<img src = 'https://placekitten.com/g/200/300'>
```